# How to fetch and display the array value using codeigniter?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model-view-controller, view

how to fetch and display the array value using codeigniter. I have added in view page but not getting the output.Let me know how to call a function along with value and show result again to view page

```
Controller.page
----------------
public function abc($id,$company)
{
$result_array['memberTo'] =$this->Admin_model->Abc($id,$company);
$this->load->view('admin_dashboard',$result_array);
}

View.page
----------------
$CI =& get_instance();             
$CI->abc($name_mem,$company);  
echo $memberTo[0]->name; 

model.page
----------------
public function Abc($id,$company){

  // echo $db_name = $company."_db"; 

  $this->dbm = $this->load->database('$db_name', true);
  $this->db->where('folio', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get('members');
        $data = array();
        foreach($result->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: Your view is admin dashboard???

Comment: If you change your view code with `var_dump($memberTo');`, what do yo see?

Comment: devpro@ Yes admin_dashboard.php

Comment: Tpojka @ it is showing Undefined variable: memberTo

Answer (score 0):

You Change in You model function and View page

try like this
Model Page

```
public function Abc($id,$company){
// echo $db_name = $company."_db"; 
 $this->dbm = $this->load->database('$db_name', true);


$this->db->where('folio', $id);
    $result = $this->db->get('members');
    $data = array();

    return $result;

}
```

in Your View Page

```
$CI =& get_instance();             
$CI->abc($name_mem,$company);  
foreach($memberTo->result() as $row)
{
echo $row->name; 
}
```

Comment: Getting error as Call to a member function result() on a non-object in

Comment: in Controller : array(1) {
  ["memberTo"]=>
  object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#25 (8) {
    ["conn_id"]=>
    resource(81) of type (mysql link persistent)
    ["result_id"]=>
    resource(82) of type (mysql result)
    ["result_array"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["result_object"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#46 (45) {
        ["tolio"]=>
        string(8) "1481"
        ["title"]=>
        string(2) "MR"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "Yogai K"
        ["trust_name"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["mm_address1"]=>
        string(11) "DENTAL DEPT"

Comment: you need single record or multiple record .if you need single record try this
$row=$memberTo->row();echo $row->name(); else multiple record need try this foreach($memberTo->result() as $row){echo $row->name;}